# overlapping ranges SAS

Tags: variables, sas

I am trying to create a new variable in SAS and have the following code:

```
    if (Age >= 16) and (Age <= 85) then Age_New = "Total, 16 years and over";
else if (Age >= 16) and (Age <= 19) then Age_New = "16 to 19 years";
else if (Age >= 20) and (Age <= 85) then Age_New = "20 years and over";
else if (Age >= 20) and (Age <= 24) then Age_New = "20 to 24 years";
else if (Age >= 25) and (Age <= 85) then Age_New = "25 years and over";
else if (Age >= 25) and (Age <= 54) then Age_New = "25 to 54 years";
else if (Age >= 55) and (Age <= 85) then Age_New = "55 years and over";
else if (Age >= 55) and (Age <= 64) then Age_New = "55 to 64 years";
else if (Age >= 65) and (Age <= 85) then Age_New = "65 years and over";
else Age_New = "Other";
```

NOw what keeps happening is that I get the value of "Total, 16 years and over" for all the observations and I understand why. How can I edit the code to accomplish the task I am trying to achieve?

Comment: I reckon your objective is a summary of the overlapping groups.  Using the IF statements (sans ELSE) you have you would need to output an observation for for each hit.  then DO: AGE_NEW=...; OUTPUT; END To make it work you would also need to remove the ELSE parts.  SAS has a nice feature to make this easier called a "Multi-Label-Format".  You don't need a new variable or to manufacture any observations.  Go to PROC FORMAT and read about it and then look at examples in PROC MEANS/SUMMARY or TABULATE to see how it can be used.

Comment: I actually know about the prof format option, but I actually needed to create a new dataset with this new variable for other purposes.

Comment: You look like you're asking for one variable to have two values.  That's not really possible... unless you use MLF, as DN notes above, anyway.  What are you actually trying to do (that is actually possible)?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a format then you can create observations.

```
data have;
   input age;
   cards;
16
18
22
33
44
55
66
77
;;;;
   run;
data need;
   set have;
   if (Age >= 16) and (Age <= 85) then do; Age_New = "Total, 16 years and over"; output; end;
   if (Age >= 16) and (Age <= 19) then do; Age_New = "16 to 19 years";           output; end;
   if (Age >= 20) and (Age <= 85) then do; Age_New = "20 years and over";        output; end;
   if (Age >= 20) and (Age <= 24) then do; Age_New = "20 to 24 years";           output; end;
   if (Age >= 25) and (Age <= 85) then do; Age_New = "25 years and over";        output; end;
   if (Age >= 25) and (Age <= 54) then do; Age_New = "25 to 54 years";           output; end;
   if (Age >= 55) and (Age <= 85) then do; Age_New = "55 years and over";        output; end;
   if (Age >= 55) and (Age <= 64) then do; Age_New = "55 to 64 years";           output; end; 
   if (Age >= 65) and (Age <= 85) then do; Age_New = "65 years and over";        output; end;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc freq;
   tables age_new / list nocum nopercent;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if-then-else clauses are not mutually exclusive. All the if statements where the Age <= 85 is inclusive of all numbers hence the first 'if-statement' that has the Age <= 85 will be enforced instead. I took out all the statement where you placed and (Age <= 85) and it showed the expected results.

```
data have;
   input age;
   cards;
16
18
22
33
44
55
66
77


;
data have;
   set have;
if (Age >= 16) and (Age <= 19) then Age_New = "16 to 19 years";
else if (Age >= 20) and (Age <= 24) then Age_New = "20 to 24 years";
else if (Age >= 25) and (Age <= 54) then Age_New = "25 to 54 years";
else if (Age >= 55) and (Age <= 64) then Age_New = "55 to 64 years";
else Age_New = "Other";
run;
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really help,  because I still need "Total, 16 years and over";. But I appreciate it.

Comment: You can't have both '16 to 19 years' and 'total 16 years and over' unless they are two different variables. They both include ages from 16-19 so you need to tell SAS which of the two you want to keep.

Comment: In an if-then-else statement, in order for SAS to check the else-if statement and execute, the first if clause has to be false. The way you coded it, the first if-statement will never be false if all your values are between 16-85.